# How to group values and sum in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Consider this pandas data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['city','pop'])
df['city'] = ['faa','foo','faa','faa','foo']
df['pop'] = [10,20,15,30,60]

  city  pop
0  faa   10
1  foo   20
2  faa   15
3  faa   30
4  foo   60
```

How to sum the pop of each city? I'd like to obtain

```
   city  pop
0   faa   55
1   foo   80
```

Comment: @ALollz, perfect. It is exactly that. I didn't know how to search for.

Comment: Reading the Pandas docs should point you in the right direction.  For your application you want to use groupby.  e.g. popCount = df.groupby(by='city', as_index=False).sum()